# CSS and JQuery doesn't work after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

My excuses: First off all, I would like to explain that I've been searching for an answer a long time. I found so many similar questions, but none with a solution for my scenario.

The Problem: After an Ajax call, where I dinamicaly add HTML code, the code added looses its styles and action responses (on click, for example).

HTML : The HTML that is loaded with page loading. It renders the collection of the user's images correctly. I mean... the style is ok and the JS functions bind to the classes 'visualizaImagem' and 'deletaImagem' works fine.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" id='imagens'>
        <?php 
        if(isset($imagens)){

            if(count($imagens) > 0){

                foreach($imagens as $imagem){

                    echo "
                    <div class='file-box' data-path='" . $imagem['path'] . "' id='" . $imagem['nome'] . "'>
                        <div class='file'>
                            <a class='visualizaImagem' data-path='". $imagem['path'] ."'>
                                <div class='icon'>
                                    <img src='../" . $imagem['path'] . "' style='height:100%'>
                                    <a class='deletaImagem' data-path='". $imagem['path'] ."' data-divid='" . $imagem['nome'] . "'>
                                        <i class='fa fa-trash' style='position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;font-size:18px;'></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class='file-name'> " . $imagem['nome'] . "</div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>";
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS : When I click to the upload button (that is not part of this code), the image data is passed through "data: dados", read by "salvaImagem" in the specific controller and than appended to the page. The image is actually appended, but with no css style and no response to the functions that should have been bind to the same classes presented above.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "salvaImagem",
        data: dados,
        dataType: "json"}).done(function(response)
        {
            if(response.sucesso){

                toastr['success'](response.msg);

                var img = "" +
                        "<div class='file-box' id='" + response.nome + "' data-path='" + response.path + "'>" +
                        "   <div class='file'>" +
                        "       <a class='visualizaImagem' data-path='"+response.path+"'>" +
                        "           <div class='icon'>" +
                        "               <img src='../"+response.path+"' style='height:100%'>" +
                        "               <a class='deletaImagem' data-path='"+response.path+"' data-divid='"+response.nome+"'>" +
                        "                   <i class='fa fa-trash' style='position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;font-size:18px;'>" +
                        "               </a>" +
                        "           </div>" +
                        "           <div class='file-name'> "+response.nome+"</div>" +
                        "       </a>" +
                        "   </div>" +
                        "</div>";

                $('#imagens').append(img);
            }
            else{
                toastr['error'](response.msg);
            }
        });
```

I think I should give a little bit more about the code. Here is an example of how I bind functions to those classes. Actually as I wrote the function inside the bind, I was expecting that would't be necessary to rebind.

```
$('.deletaImagem').on('click', function (){
    var path = $(this).data('path');
    var div_id = $(this).data('divid');

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "deletaImagem",
        data: {'path':path},
        dataType: "json"}).done(function(response)
        {
            if(response.sucesso){

                toastr['success'](response.msg);
                $('#'+div_id).remove();                 
            }
            else{
                toastr['error'](response.msg);
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

Trying to use some of the tips friends gave me here, I tried the following, but no success either.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "salvaImagem",
        data: dados,
        dataType: "json"}).done(function(response)
        {
            if(response.sucesso){

                toastr['success'](response.msg);

                var img = <HTML original code here>

                $(img).appendTo('#imagens').find('.deletaImagem').on('click', deletaImagem);
                $('.visualizaImagem').on('click', visualizaImagem);
            }
            else{
                toastr['error'](response.msg);
            }
        });

 function deletaImagem(){
    var path = $(this).data('path');
    var div_id = $(this).data('divid');

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "deletaImagem",
        data: {'path':path},
        dataType: "json"}).done(function(response)
        {
            if(response.sucesso){

                $('#'+div_id).remove(); 
                toastr['success'](response.msg);
            }
            else{
                toastr['error'](response.msg);
            }
        });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I assume you are binding events (click etc... ) on document.ready, any new items added later will not have those events.

After adding the the new items, just add the events again.

```
$('#something').append("<div class='somethingWithClicklistener'>a</div>"); // It won't have the event, you have to add it
$('.somethingWithClicklistener').click(function(){ etc..
```

Though that approach might double the event handlers on pre-existing classes but you get the point

As for styles it shouldn't happen unless you use jquery animation etc...

Comment: Moussa... I gave some more of my code. I wrote the functions inside the bindings, thinking this way I wouldnt need to rebind them. Maybe I should change it a little and force a rebind. Thank you. I will give you a plus, but will wait a little for a closer solution.

Comment: @CarlosOst You would need to create a dom object and give it the listener specifically. Check phreakv6's answer it's in that route

Answer (score 1):

if you get an ajax response as html, you have to write your javascript code relatively to your root element in witch you input your html (received from ajax).

1.

```
<div class="some-root-div">
    // the place where you put your html from response
</div>
```

2. And you should append the html like this: `$('#imagens').append($(img))`;

3.

```
(function($){
    "use strict";
    $('.some-root-div', '.deletaImagem').on('click', function(){
        // your logic on `.deletaImagem` link click
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that event handlers are not being attached to the new elements. It is pretty simple to do so while you attach the element to the DOM.

Change this

```
$('#imagens').append(img);
```

to

```
$(img).appendTo('#imagens').find('.deletaImagem').on('click', function (){
    var path = $(this).data('path');
    var div_id = $(this).data('divid');

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "deletaImagem",
        data: {'path':path},
        dataType: "json"}).done(function(response)
        {
            if(response.sucesso){

                toastr['success'](response.msg);
                $('#'+div_id).remove();                 
            }
            else{
                toastr['error'](response.msg);
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Sorry phreakv6, but I think you didn't notice that in case of success of this specific ajax call, I remove the image from the page '$('#'+div_id).remove()'. How could I add it, by removing it :-).

Comment: Another point is that 'img' is the dinamicaly formed string to be appended to the page. How could I form it before know wich information would compose it? Thank you anyway, but I think this is not the answer yet.

Comment: I have updated my solution to use

$(img).appendTo('#imagens').find('.deletaImagem').on('click'

This will essentially attach your onclick handler to the deletaImagem class of the newly added img element. What we are doing here is not removing the the image but attaching a handler to remove the image (the newly, dynamically added image) when delete is clicked.

Comment: I think we are getting closer, but I need a function to bind the images that are appended on the page load. I mean... I bring some images from the server and those images also need to be binded to the delete function. I tried $(img).appendTo('#imagens').find('.deletaImagem').on('click', deletaImagem); but it didn't work.

Comment: Is deletaImagem being called for the newly attached element? Try adding a console.log() or alert() within that function and see.

Answer (score 0):

I've been here. My solution and understanding is that AJAX comes at the end/during javascript, javascript coming way after CSS. I ended up setting the styles that need to be the most dynamic in javascript with a function that takes an element as a parameter. works like a charm!

```
function styleElement(elem){
    elem.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```